# How to access Mustache file inside javascript function [updated]?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have some data which is stored in ArrayList in java code and I am using Mustache to display the results of myArray on my HTML webpage.

myIndex.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var plotMapHidden = true;
        {{{myArray}}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card-body">
    {{#myArray}}
    <strong> {{.}} </strong> <br>
    {{/myArray}}
</div>
<script >
    // I want to access {{myArray}} data here as well like var newArray = {{myArray}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way that I can access Mustache data inside the script as shown above?

HTML output the div section successfully (`[1,2,...,100]`). I want to reuse the myArray data in  section as well to do other javascript functions. thanks

Comment: Mustache looks to be parsing the template file and replacing all the mustache tags with data, so there's no reason why you couldn't get it to work. You'll need to make sure it expands the mustache tag into a valid JavaScript list [ a, b, c, ... ]

Comment: @SimonJacobs Thanks for your comment. It would be great if you have any suggestions on how to expand it. I still couldn't find the way to do it. thanks

Comment: The Java readme file looks helpful https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/blob/master/README.md for examples to follow. It looks like you can't expand an ArrayList of plain strings; instead it needs to be of an object with a named property. Then you could do <script>var jsList = [ {{#myArray}} {{namedProperty}}, {{/myArray}} ]</script>. For more guidance you'll have to show the relevant parts of your Java code, your template and what HTML is output.

Comment: @SimonJacobs Thanks for your further comment. I designed most of my java code based on that GitHub link that you provided. I just updated my question with requested selections and codes. Please let me know if you have any further help or suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried something like: <script>var jsList = [ {{#myArray}} {{.}}, {{/myArray}} ]; window.alert( jsList)</script>?

Comment: @SimonJacobs I just tried as ```<script>var jsList = [ {{#myArray}} {{.}}, {{/myArray}} ]; window.alert( jsList)</script>``` and it is not showing the results in my html code and giving syntax error in my editor as ```Unterminated regular expression literal.javascript```, however i can see all the results in window alert in each loading.

Comment: If you see the correct output in the alert then sounds like it works! Looks like your editor doesn't recognise that way of doing things though unfortunately. That seems a rather harder problem.

Comment: @SimonJacobs I just tried ```<script>var jsList = "{{myArray}}";window.alert( jsList)</script>``` as well and alert shows correctly, however when i try to check if its accessable by ```document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsList;``` it does not work. Do you think, if there i any other soulution to this? or do you have any other method other than Mustache to use for globally access data like my problem? thanks

Comment: If the right data is shown in the window.alert() then the variable is there so something else is wrong. Are you sure you're running the scripts in the right order etc? Mustache seems to be working fine from what I can see but if it doesn't play with your editor that would be annoying. I'm sure there are plenty of Java templating engines out there though that you can try. I prefer to render client-side if I can help it!

Comment: @SimonJacobs Thanks for your comment. That's right, mustache gives the correct results in a window alert. I haven't heard about the render client-side. I will look into it now and let you know. I am looking for fixing this issue and definitely, I will acknowledge your help. thanks